# UrlToDownloadFile function not downloading

Tags: c++, msdn, urlmon

I am using UrlToDownloadFile function, but it doesn't download the file. No error shown in compiler (using VStudio 2012)

Here is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "urlmon.h"

#pragma lib "urlmon.lib"

using namespace std;

void dwFile();


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    dwFile ();
    return 0;
}

void dwFile () 
{
    LPCSTR url = ("http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf");
    LPCSTR fPath = ("C:\\Users\\Andyy\\Desktop\\test\\n3337.pdf");

    HRESULT URLDownloadToFile ((NULL, url, fPath, 0, NULL));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean perhaps `HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(...)` ?

Comment: HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile (NULL, url, fPath, 0, NULL);
I did that earlier but I get error with url and fPath, saying: LPCSTR is incompatible with LPCWSTR type. I don't know why because in msdn says  type LPCSTR .

Comment: `LPCTSTR` is a `const` pointer to a `TCHAR*` string. When you compile your project for Unicode, `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`, and `URLDownloadToFile()` maps to `URLDownloadToFileW()`. When you compile for MBCS, `TCHAR` maps to `char`, and `URLDownloadToFile()` maps to `URLDownloadToFileA()`. To assign a string literal to a `TCHAR*`  string, you need to wrap it inside the `TEXT()` macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not doing any error handling, and your string handling is wrong.  Use this instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "urlmon.h"

#pragma lib "urlmon.lib"

using namespace std;

void dwFile();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    dwFile ();
    return 0;
}

void dwFile () 
{
    LPCTSTR url = TEXT("http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf");
    LPCTSTR fPath = TEXT("C:\\Users\\Andyy\\Desktop\\test\\n3337.pdf");

    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile (NULL, url, fPath, 0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // do something ...
    }

    /* or more preffered:

    LPCWSTR url = L"http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf";
    LPCWSTR fPath = L"C:\\Users\\Andyy\\Desktop\\test\\n3337.pdf");

    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFileW (NULL, url, fPath, 0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // do something ...
    }
    */
}
```

Do note the following comment in the documentation:

> URLDownloadToFile returns S_OK **even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled**. If the szFileName parameter contains a file path, ensure that the destination directory exists before calling URLDownloadToFile. **For best control over the download and its progress, an IBindStatusCallback interface is recommended**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your example wrapped url and fPath with TEXT () macro, I get an error in both examples saying: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _URLDownloadToFileW@20 referenced in function _wmain

Comment: @Andy: Your project needs to link to `Urlmon.lib` to resolve that.

Comment: Doesn't `#pragma lib "urlmon.lib"` include the urlmon.lib?

Comment: @Andy: There is no `#pragma lib ...` directive. You should be using `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , where could I download the urlmon.lib ? I can't find it anywhere :(

Comment: @Momoro it is in the Windows SDK. It should be included by default with most compilers that support Windows development. Otherwise, you would need to download the SDK from Microsoft. Or at least use your compiler's IMPLIB (or equivalent) tool to create a LIB file from URLMON.DLL in your Windows system folder.

Comment: Well, could you direct me to the area I can download the SDK from Microsoft..? I am using Notepad to program my C++ ... (**It's a fun challenge**)